# Python Using Lists to create program

Tags: python, list, loops, nested

I have an assignment in class to write a program using lists in Python

"Create a program that prompts the user for a vocabulary word. Then prompts user to enter the word's definition. Ask user if they want to enter more words and definitions. When they are done entering all words and definitions, print out all the words along with their definition."

I know I need to have a nested list to store the user input. But my question is how am I going to get the user input and store it into a nested list? I also know that I need to use a loop to take in all the inputs for words and definitions, but I'm confused on how to do so.

---

```
myvar=str(print(input("Type a Word.")))
myvar2=str(print(input("Type the word's definition.")))
myvar3=input(print("If you want to enter another word, enter Y, if not enter N"))
mylist=[[myvar,myvar2]]
while myvar3=='Y':
    myvar4=str(print(input("Enter your next word.")))
    myvar5=str(print(input("Enter the word's definition.")))
    mylist.append([myvar4,myvar5])
    myvar3=input(print("If you want to enter another word, enter Y, if not enter N"))

print(mylist)
```

I think this works, is there anything wrong with this? Do I need to make it to where if they enter "N" it does something to end the loop? Or does the loop just end as long as it doesn't equal 'Y'?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Typically, users are expected to show code sample or other example of what they have already tried to do to solve their problem. Can you edit your question to provide such?

Comment: Where us the code? This question should be closed. A google search could answer it. This is not a code writing service.

Comment: Mhh, a word and its definition, a word and its definition, a word and its definition, ..., this looks more a dictionary than a list!

Comment: @JavkWin if you're in to become a good programmer, SO is the site for you. Full stop.  Please don't feel discouraged by some (imho unnecessary) roughness here and there. You see, Mr/ms furkle's answer is a very good starting point for your homework, look back at your class material and start coding. On the other hand, if you're in to find a code writing service, as Mr Apero clearly told you, SO is not the right place and you'd better investigate other options. Let me repeat myself: study furkle's answer, study your class notes and START CODING!  ciao from

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python 3.x, getting input from a user is very simple. This is accomplished using the input() function.

This will prompt input from the user, printing the string passed to input() before the caret:

```
input("Please enter a word: ")
```

The user types whatever they feel, then hits Enter. When they hit enter, input() *returns* the text they've entered. So, you can store the value the user typed with something like this:

```
user_word = input("Please enter a word: ")
```

And a definition can be entered into a separate variable like this:

```
user_definition = input("Please enter a definition: ")
```

Then, you can use one of Python's built-in data types to store both values, and, just as importantly, to build a logical association between them, before you prompt them for their next word.

Here's the documentation on the [input and output](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/io.html).